# Element could not be located using find element by Id

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

I am performing some UI automation and using Appium Inspector to inspect the user name text field for the Microsoft login credentials screen.
When referencing an element by Id I get the error: "An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters."

I am using Appium Inspector for Appium 2.0 and according to the recommended selector I can use either id xpath however, **id gives me the error whilst using xpath works**

[image]

The line of code which is failing:

```html
driver.FindElementById("i0116").SendKeys("test");
```

Any reason why this is the case?

**My environment is:**

- Appium server 2.0
- Android Studio - Electric Eel
- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2022 using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium C# library

```js
"desiredCapabilities": {
    "platformName": "Android",
    "appium:automationName": "UIAutomator2",
    "appium:deviceName": "PixelSix",
    "appium:app": "C:\\Users\\slai6\\Downloads\\MyApp.1.apk",
    "appium:platformVersion": "11",
    "appium:ensureWebviewsHavePages": true,
    "appium:nativeWebScreenshot": true,
    "appium:newCommandTimeout": 3600,
    "appium:connectHardwareKeyboard": true
  }
```

Comment: [so] FAQ on posting of images instead of text: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/14853083

Comment: @Stanza did you get around it?

Comment: @febaisi yeah got it working a while ago, see my response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the Microsoft login screen was part of the 'WEBVIEW' context so I had to change the context from "NATIVE_APP".

I used:

```
((IContextAware)driver).Context = "WEBVIEW";
```

I also had to install the chrome driver using:

```
driverOption.AddAdditionalCapability("appium:chromedriverExecutable", chromePath);
```

Where the 'chromePath' is the directory where I downloaded the Chrome driver to on my local machine.
I had to manually download the executable from: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

I was then able to inspect it using the Chrome inspector tool - type in **chrome://inspect** in address bar for google Chrome, select the emulator device form the device list and get the id from the inspector tool.